# Prerequisites to learn Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, self-learning, big-list

I really wanna learn Complex Analysis but I don't know where to start.

Basically I can do olympiad problems, but I don't know calculus that well, so I would appreciate it if someone can post a list of topics (preferably in chronological order, if that makes sense) for me to learn before I am absolutely 100% ready to start learning the complex analysis, which I've read about and think is A-M-A-Z-I-N-G.

Thank you for your time everyone! :D

Comment: For the most part, you only need to be familiar with basic concepts in real analysis (especially topics related to convergence of sequences, series, and integrals).

Comment: You should learn calculus better and learn some basic multivariable calculus. The idea of a contour integral is a little weird at first but once you make the connection to line integrals it's fairly intuitive. I suggest you learn a little bit of topology since it shows up a bit in complex analysis. Knowing real analysis to a decent extent is necessary if you want to know complex analysis rigorously.

Answer (score 11):

Sequences and series of numbers and of vectors

Derivative in one variable

Integration in one variable

Integration with parameters (i.e. of the form $f(x) = \int_D \phi(x,t)\, dt$)

Sequences and series of functions

Uniform vs. pointwise convergence

Derivative in several variables

Line integrals

Topology of metric spaces

I'm told that the Stewart text is good for learning calculus for the first time.

If you're looking for a challenge, Buck's *Advanced Calculus* is rigorous. He even introduces complex variables at the end.

If you want a fun introduction without too much rigor, there are some popular books on complex variables, such as *An Imaginary Tale: The Story of $\sqrt{-1}$*.

Comment: I would not recommend Stewart Calculus to anyone, unless it has changed a lot in the last 7 years.

Comment: @ArkanMegraoui "Real analysis" is a type of analysis, usually the first kind you learn. Calculus is the first part of real analysis.

Comment: @Eric: I realize you're a fan of Buck, but I've never been. It's dated. It's time to think in terms of vector functions, not ordered pairs (or triples) of real-valued functions.

Comment: @TedShifrin What books on the subject are your favorites?

Comment: @Eric: For the single-variable material, there are lots of readable books, like William Wade's *Introduction to Analysis*. I have always liked C.H. Edwards's *Advanced Calculus of Several Variables* (now in Dover). And of course I have to mention my own *Multivariable Mathematics* (which does not presume prior knowledge of multivariable calculus or linear algebra, but does a good deal of multivariable analysis).

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation of *An Imaginary Tale: The Story of $\sqrt{-1}$*, I am having great fun reading it now. It's really an excellent book for someone like me who is interested in mathematics but is not a mathematician by any means.

Answer (score 3):

This goes along with the excellent advice you have gotten so far. Learning calculus is, of course, an important step. Then you might consider learning real analysis. It is usually the transition to rigorous math, which is, in it's entirety, as you say amazing.

This set of lecture notes by Fields Medal winner Vaughan Jones (like the Nobel Prize in math) are fabulous. A master, giving great insight as to how to think about things, starting from a position of no prior experience. So it's great for self-learning. They are free for downloading. The last part is a rigorous presentation of a good deal of calculus - which will be invaluable in CA studies.

https://sites.google.com/site/math104sp2011/lecture-notes

I am sure once you actually start complex analysis you can get excellent recommendation for study materials here. But I might suggest Flanigan.

[http://www.amazon.com/Complex-Variables-Dover-Books-Mathematics/dp/0486613887](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486613887)

It rigorous, but makes things very clear with the added feature of many examples and pictures, not to be underestimated as an aid to visualization (redundancy intended).

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The most useful topics to cover, which relate directly to complex analysis are:

- integration (1 variable)
- differentiation (1 variable)
- and basic topology

Yaseen